# How to create sh compatible bash function

Tags: bash, shell, process-substitution

I have this bash function:

```
zmx(){
 "$@"  \
      2> >( while read line; do echo -e "r2g: $line"; done ) \
      1> >( while read line; do echo -e "r2g: $line"; done )
}
```

this function is only supposed to be sourced and run by bash, but for some godforsaken reason, it's being sourced/run by sh.

You use the above function like so:

```
zmx foo bar
```

and it will prepend `r2g:` to the stdout/stderr from the foo command.

So my question is — does anyone know how to translate the above bash function into something sh can work with?

Right now I get a syntax error when sh interprets that function. I have been struggling for months to figure out why sh is invoked to interpret the function, but I pretty much gave up trying to prevent sh from doing so.

Comment: Why are you using `echo -e`? Do you specifically want to expand escaped characters?

Answer (score 2):

Here’s another approach which works with POSIX `sh`:

```
zmx() {
    "$@" 2>&1 | sed 's/^/r2g: /'
}
```

This avoids having to deal with `read`’s subtleties.

To check such shell snippets yourself, you can use [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/): add a `#!/bin/sh` shebang to tell it you want to use a POSIX shell, and it will tell you what to fix.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work in `sh`:

```
"$@" 2>&1 | while read line ; do echo -e "r2g: $line" ; done
```

Note that the behaviour of `echo -e` might be different in sh (e.g. it might actually output `-e r2g: ...`.)

Comment: Yes, POSIX `sh` ignores `-e`. This also mangles backslashes (thanks to `read`).

Comment: And leading whitespace. @StephenKitt

Comment: Why not just use `printf` then?

Comment: I'm not sure why the `-e` was there from the beginning. `printf` needs to be tested, the variable might contain some `%` that you don't want to be interpreted, but some `\t` or whatever that you want to interpret.